# C# with Newtonsoft JSON.Net, how to parse a more complicated JSON object

Tags: .net, json, json.net

I'm starting to use Newtonsoft's JSON.net to parse a JSON file. I could find any good tutorial on how to parse multi-level deep objects.

Can you please help give me some example? thank you.

For example, I want to get the `Search.results`'s value 16513100, and for each node in the "Tweets" section, `content->Poloarity's value = Neutral`

What I have so far:

```
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename));

string TotalCount = ((JProperty)((JContainer)((JContainer)o1.First).First).First).Value.ToString();
string CurrentCount = ((JProperty)((JContainer)((JContainer)o1.First).First).Last).Value.ToString();
```

### Below is the JSON text:

```
{
  "related": { "next": { "href": "https://cdeservice.mybluemix.net:443/api/v1/messages/search?q=Apple&from=100&size=100" } },
  "search": {
    "results": 16513100,
    "current": 100
  },
  "tweets": [
    {
      "cde": {
        "author": {
          "gender": "unknown",
          "parenthood": {
            "isParent": "unknown",
            "evidence": ""
          },
          "location": { },
          "maritalStatus": {
            "isMarried": "unknown",
            "evidence": ""
          }
        },
        "content": {
          "sentiment": {
            "evidence": [ ],
            "polarity": "NEUTRAL"
          }
        }
      },
      "cdeInternal": { "tracks": [ { "id": "2713720a-f341-4ca0-acd1-f8b1e6c0d00f" } ] },
      "message": {
        "postedTime": "2014-10-18T14:52:52.000Z",
        "verb": "share",
        "link": "http://twitter.com/CyMadD0x/statuses/523486878075744257",
        "generator": {
          "displayName": "Twitter for Android",
          "link": "http://twitter.com/download/android"
        },
        "body": "RT @LionelMedia: NYPD Commissioner Bratton vows to push against Apple, Google smartphone encryption http://something",
        "favoritesCount": 0,
        "objectType": "activity",
        "actor": {
          "summary": "4|\\|uVv@ kN0d3 1n 73H |/|ëTz",
          "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/505216574781792256/lD-6Hg_K_normal.jpeg",
          "statusesCount": 226174,
          "utcOffset": null,
          "languages": [ "en" ],
          "preferredUsername": "CyMadD0x",
          "displayName": "Film The Police",
          "postedTime": "2011-12-03T02:06:28.000Z",
          "link": "http://www.twitter.com/CyMadD0x",
          "verified": false,
          "friendsCount": 3918,
          "twitterTimeZone": null,
          "favoritesCount": 62255,
          "listedCount": 167,
          "objectType": "person",
          "links": [
            {
              "rel": "me",
              "href": null
            }
          ],
          "id": "id:twitter.com:427062600",
          "followersCount": 3666
        },
        "provider": {
          "displayName": "Twitter",
          "link": "http://www.twitter.com",
          "objectType": "service"
        },
        "twitter_filter_level": "medium",
        "twitter_entities": {
          "urls": [
            {
              "display_url": "something/76V2IBVi9",
              "indices": [ 100, 122 ],
              "expanded_url": "http://something/76V2IBVi9",
              "url": "http://something"
            }
          ],
          "hashtags": [ ],
          "user_mentions": [
            {
              "indices": [ 3, 15 ],
              "screen_name": "LionelMedia",
              "id_str": "24787367",
              "name": "Lionel",
              "id": 24787367
            }
          ],
          "trends": [ ],
          "symbols": [ ]
        },
        "twitter_lang": "en",
        "id": "tag:search.twitter.com,2005:523486878075744257",
        "retweetCount": 1,
        "gnip": {
          "urls": [
            {
              "expanded_url": "http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/nypd-bratton-vows-push-apple-google-smartphone-encryption-article-1.1978719",
              "expanded_status": 200,
              "url": "http://seomthing"
            }
          ],
          "language": { "value": "fr" }
        },
        "object": {
          "postedTime": "2014-10-18T14:48:39.000Z",
          "verb": "post",
          "link": "http://twitter.com/LionelMedia/statuses/523485817625657344",
          "generator": {
            "displayName": "Facebook",
            "link": "http://www.facebook.com/twitter"
          },
          "body": "NYPD Commissioner Bratton vows to push against Apple, Google smartphone encryption http://something",
          "favoritesCount": 0,
          "objectType": "activity",
          "actor": {
            "summary": "LOTUS (Lionel of the U.S.) - The bravest man in media. Renaissance lawyer, vegan, news decoder, conspiracy analyst not theorist. DM: lionel@lionelmedia.com",
            "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1872109972/LIONEL_HEADSHOT_normal",
            "statusesCount": 125171,
            "utcOffset": "-14400",
            "languages": [ "en" ],
            "preferredUsername": "LionelMedia",
            "displayName": "Lionel",
            "postedTime": "2009-03-16T22:45:21.000Z",
            "link": "http://www.twitter.com/LionelMedia",
            "verified": false,
            "friendsCount": 581,
            "twitterTimeZone": "Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
            "favoritesCount": 216,
            "listedCount": 239,
            "objectType": "person",
            "links": [
              {
                "rel": "me",
                "href": "http://lionelmedia.com"
              }
            ],
            "location": {
              "displayName": "Hell's Kitchen, USA",
              "objectType": "place"
            },
            "id": "id:twitter.com:24787367",
            "followersCount": 9951
          },
          "provider": {
            "displayName": "Twitter",
            "link": "http://www.twitter.com",
            "objectType": "service"
          },
          "twitter_filter_level": "low",
          "twitter_entities": {
            "urls": [
              {
                "display_url": "something/76V2IBVi9",
                "indices": [ 83, 105 ],
                "expanded_url": "http://something/76V2IBVi9",
                "url": "http://something"
              }
            ],
            "hashtags": [ ],
            "user_mentions": [ ],
            "trends": [ ],
            "symbols": [ ]
          },
          "twitter_lang": "en",
          "id": "tag:search.twitter.com,2005:523485817625657344",
          "object": {
            "summary": "NYPD Commissioner Bratton vows to push against Apple, Google smartphone encryption http://something",
            "postedTime": "2014-10-18T14:48:39.000Z",
            "link": "http://twitter.com/LionelMedia/statuses/523485817625657344",
            "id": "object:search.twitter.com,2005:523485817625657344",
            "objectType": "note"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "cde": {
        "author": {
          "gender": "male",
          "parenthood": {
            "isParent": "unknown",
            "evidence": ""
          },
          "location": {
            "country": "Ireland",
            "city": "",
            "state": ""
          },
          "maritalStatus": {
            "isMarried": "unknown",
            "evidence": ""
          }
        },
        "content": {
          "sentiment": {
            "evidence": [
              {
                "polarity": "NEGATIVE",
                "sentimentTerm": "stereotype"
              }
            ],
            "polarity": "NEGATIVE"
          }
        }
      },
      "cdeInternal": { "tracks": [ { "id": "2713720a-f341-4ca0-acd1-f8b1e6c0d00f" } ] },
      "message": {
        "twitter_extended_entities": {
          "media": [
            {
              "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/JwXAJbPxms",
              "indices": [ 104, 126 ],
              "sizes": {
                "small": {
                  "w": 340,
                  "h": 305,
                  "resize": "fit"
                },
                "large": {
                  "w": 1024,
                  "h": 918,
                  "resize": "fit"
                },
                "thumb": {
                  "w": 150,
                  "h": 150,
                  "resize": "crop"
                },
                "medium": {
                  "w": 600,
                  "h": 538,
                  "resize": "fit"
                }
              },
              "id_str": "523494030517084160",
              "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/theapplefarmer/status/523494051019235328/photo/1",
              "source_status_id_str": "523494051019235328",
              "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B0PTDBMCIAAcd61.jpg",
              "id": 523494030517084160,
              "type": "photo",
              "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/B0PTDBMCIAAcd61.jpg",
              "source_status_id": 523494051019235328,
              "url": "http://something"
            }
          ]
        },
        "postedTime": "2014-10-18T15:48:33.000Z",
        "verb": "share",
        "link": "http://twitter.com/McKennasGuides/statuses/523500890398154752",
        "generator": {
          "displayName": "Twitter for iPhone",
          "link": "http://twitter.com/download/iphone"
        },
        "body": "RT @theapplefarmer: Elstar apples now on sale. Cue stereotype picture of an apple with leaf attached... http://something",
        "favoritesCount": 0,
        "objectType": "activity",
        "actor": {
          "summary": "Sally tweets.",
          "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000682481838/0dc56479e41d25fa6c4a9056c351f866_normal.jpeg",
          "statusesCount": 12203,
          "utcOffset": "3600",
          "languages": [ "en" ],
          "preferredUsername": "McKennasGuides",
          "displayName": "John & Sally McKenna",
          "postedTime": "2010-03-10T15:38:14.000Z",
          "link": "http://www.twitter.com/McKennasGuides",
          "verified": false,
          "friendsCount": 1148,
          "twitterTimeZone": "Dublin",
          "favoritesCount": 982,
          "listedCount": 131,
          "objectType": "person",
          "links": [
            {
              "rel": "me",
              "href": "http://www.guides.ie"
            }
          ],
          "location": {
            "displayName": "Ireland",
            "objectType": "place"
          },
          "id": "id:twitter.com:121784956",
          "followersCount": 12032
        },
        "provider": {
          "displayName": "Twitter",
          "link": "http://www.twitter.com",
          "objectType": "service"
        },
        "twitter_filter_level": "medium",
        "twitter_entities": {
          "urls": [ ],
          "hashtags": [ ],
          "media": [
            {
              "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/JwXAJbPxms",
              "indices": [ 104, 126 ],
              "sizes": {
                "small": {
                  "w": 340,
                  "h": 305,
                  "resize": "fit"
                },
                "large": {
                  "w": 1024,
                  "h": 918,
                  "resize": "fit"
                },
                "thumb": {
                  "w": 150,
                  "h": 150,
                  "resize": "crop"
                },
                "medium": {
                  "w": 600,
                  "h": 538,
                  "resize": "fit"
                }
              },
              "id_str": "523494030517084160",
              "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/theapplefarmer/status/523494051019235328/photo/1",
              "source_status_id_str": "523494051019235328",
              "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B0PTDBMCIAAcd61.jpg",
              "id": 523494030517084160,
              "type": "photo",
              "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/B0PTDBMCIAAcd61.jpg",
              "source_status_id": 523494051019235328,
              "url": "http://something"
            }
          ],
          "user_mentions": [
            {
              "indices": [ 3, 18 ],
              "screen_name": "theapplefarmer",
              "id_str": "303651044",
              "name": "Cornelius Traas",
              "id": 303651044
            }
          ],
          "trends": [ ],
          "symbols": [ ]
        },
        "twitter_lang": "en",
        "id": "tag:search.twitter.com,2005:523500890398154752",
        "retweetCount": 1,
        "gnip": {
          "urls": [
            {
              "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/theapplefarmer/status/523494051019235328/photo/1",
              "expanded_status": 200,
              "url": "http://something"
            }
          ],
          "profileLocations": [
            {
              "geo": {
                "coordinates": [ -8.0, 53.0 ],
                "type": "point"
              },
              "address": {
                "country": "Ireland",
                "countryCode": "IE"
              },
              "displayName": "Ireland",
              "objectType": "place"
            }
          ],
          "language": { "value": "en" }
        },
        "object": {
          "twitter_extended_entities": {
            "media": [
              {
                "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/JwXAJbPxms",
                "indices": [ 84, 106 ],
                "sizes": {
                  "small": {
                    "w": 340,
                    "h": 305,
                    "resize": "fit"
                  },
                  "large": {
                    "w": 1024,
                    "h": 918,
                    "resize": "fit"
                  },
                  "thumb": {
                    "w": 150,
                    "h": 150,
                    "resize": "crop"
                  },
                  "medium": {
                    "w": 600,
                    "h": 538,
                    "resize": "fit"
                  }
                },
                "id_str": "523494030517084160",
                "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/theapplefarmer/status/523494051019235328/photo/1",
                "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B0PTDBMCIAAcd61.jpg",
                "id": 523494030517084160,
                "type": "photo",
                "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/B0PTDBMCIAAcd61.jpg",
                "url": "http://something"
              }
            ]
          },
          "postedTime": "2014-10-18T15:21:22.000Z",
          "verb": "post",
          "link": "http://twitter.com/theapplefarmer/statuses/523494051019235328",
          "generator": {
            "displayName": "Twitter for Android",
            "link": "http://twitter.com/download/android"
          },
          "body": "Elstar apples now on sale. Cue stereotype picture of an apple with leaf attached... http://something/JwXAJbPxms",
          "favoritesCount": 3,
          "objectType": "activity",
          "actor": {
            "summary": "Fruit grower, juice maker, university lecturer, horticultural scientist.",
            "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/461130678499676160/iIGjV61N_normal.jpeg",
            "statusesCount": 7952,
            "utcOffset": "3600",
            "languages": [ "en" ],
            "preferredUsername": "theapplefarmer",
            "displayName": "Cornelius Traas",
            "postedTime": "2011-05-23T07:27:59.000Z",
            "link": "http://www.twitter.com/theapplefarmer",
            "verified": false,
            "friendsCount": 2147,
            "twitterTimeZone": "Dublin",
            "favoritesCount": 236,
            "listedCount": 65,
            "objectType": "person",
            "links": [
              {
                "rel": "me",
                "href": "http://www.theapplefarm.com"
              }
            ],
            "location": {
              "displayName": "Tipperary, Ireland",
              "objectType": "place"
            },
            "id": "id:twitter.com:303651044",
            "followersCount": 2569
          },
          "provider": {
            "displayName": "Twitter",
            "link": "http://www.twitter.com",
            "objectType": "service"
          },
          "twitter_filter_level": "low",
          "twitter_entities": {
            "urls": [ ],
            "hashtags": [ ],
            "media": [
              {
                "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/JwXAJbPxms",
                "indices": [ 84, 106 ],
                "sizes": {
                  "small": {
                    "w": 340,
                    "h": 305,
                    "resize": "fit"
                  },
                  "large": {
                    "w": 1024,
                    "h": 918,
                    "resize": "fit"
                  },
                  "thumb": {
                    "w": 150,
                    "h": 150,
                    "resize": "crop"
                  },
                  "medium": {
                    "w": 600,
                    "h": 538,
                    "resize": "fit"
                  }
                },
                "id_str": "523494030517084160",
                "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/theapplefarmer/status/523494051019235328/photo/1",
                "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B0PTDBMCIAAcd61.jpg",
                "id": 523494030517084160,
                "type": "photo",
                "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/B0PTDBMCIAAcd61.jpg",
                "url": "http://something/JwXAJbPxms"
              }
            ],
            "user_mentions": [ ],
            "trends": [ ],
            "symbols": [ ]
          },
          "twitter_lang": "en",
          "location": {
            "geo": {
              "coordinates": [
                [
                  [ -8.4057899, 52.2013149 ],
                  [ -8.4057899, 52.7335849 ],
                  [ -7.3718273, 52.7335849 ],
                  [ -7.3718273, 52.2013149 ]
                ]
              ],
              "type": "Polygon"
            },
            "country_code": "Ireland",
            "displayName": "South Tipperary",
            "name": "South Tipperary",
            "twitter_country_code": "IE",
            "link": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/2edf98027d556c5f.json",
            "objectType": "place",
            "twitter_place_type": "city"
          },
          "id": "tag:search.twitter.com,2005:523494051019235328",
          "object": {
            "summary": "Elstar apples now on sale. Cue stereotype picture of an apple with leaf attached... http://something/JwXAJbPxms",
            "postedTime": "2014-10-18T15:21:22.000Z",
            "link": "http://twitter.com/theapplefarmer/statuses/523494051019235328",
            "id": "object:search.twitter.com,2005:523494051019235328",
            "objectType": "note"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
}
]
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid json, did you leave something out? Also we need to see some effort and code, what have you tried?

Comment: @rvpals It's not about complete, it's about valid. Cut it down to a representative (!) sample and make sure there are no syntax errors.

Comment: Yup, I just pasted the edited JSON. I'm trying to parse this object, but not sure where to start.

Comment: are you generating this json or consuming it from somewhere else?  have you tried pasting into http://json2csharp.com/ to generate class then using json.net todeserailize to your object graph.  then just use linq to query it?

Comment: I also made changes to JSON code, where it contains fly.me URL shorteners, I replaced with something, otherwise, I can't post code with URL shortener. 

It's an API that I'm using to retrieve bunch of tweets using a keyword. First node contain search result count, second node contains all the tweets. In each tweet node it contains more subnodes that contains various information.

Comment: when I'm trying to get a model with json2csharp.com, i get the complete right model. - I don't see any problem here. So if we get the right poco-class, Json.NET should get it. Just use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>`. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I like json2csharp.com. I will look into it. I did not know you can do that !!! :)

Comment: @Matthias Burger  Can you please give me an code example on how you do this? with both the generated class and how to parse the object? Thanks.

Comment: go to www.json2csharp.com there's a textfield. copy your json in and click on `generate`. now you get the C#-poco-model. You have to copy it, check it and change some things. Like duplicate classnames `Size1` and `Size2` that are both the same, delete all duplicates and call the class `Size` (But there are possibly more). So now, you have your class-structure. with `RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(your json-string)` you should be able to deserialize the json-string. try it.

Comment: sorry, the model is too large - I won't copy it as an answere ;) just try it and if you have more questions, just ask.

Comment: Thank you, Mathias. It works for me now. Appreciate it very much. :)

Comment: Mathias, what's the efficiency of using Json.NET with method like DeserializeObject, supposed I have 5000 tweets nodes in the JSON. Would that take a long time and run out of memory? The project I'm working on might involve returns of up to 1000s.

Comment: Mhh... interresting question. I have to be sorry, that I don't have an answere to it :D I never had problems with json.net. But most time, I didn't have large files. I'd carefully claim, that the limit is C# and your PC-hardware. But I really don't know.

Comment: `Newtonsoft.JSON`’s documentation suggests to use [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) for this sort of thing. It would result in much more readable code than what you have.